# List of US Time Zones for PHP to use?

Tags: php, timezone

Is there just a list of time zones for the united states I can use with php? Im using the timezone names from php such as America/Anchorage, php lists time zones here:

http://us.php.net/manual/en/timezones.others.php

I want to display them in a drop down for the user to select but I only need the ones for the US, I dont want to show a bunch that are outside the US.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.america.php

Comment: @Shakti Singh Thank you, but that is for all of America. Just want the ones for United States.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't hand pick them yourself from the list?

Comment: @David Kuridza Was just looking for something a little more automated. But no worries, looks like I found what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: **+1 to open**, while technically a list it is directly programming related. There are too many people with reputation on Stack and in RL that don't deserve the powers granted to them.

Comment: Go to the final 2 examples in my answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/68690406/4188092 to get a list of timezones filtered by country code using the php intl module.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

Here is a list I found:

```
Eastern Time    America/New_York
Central Time    America/Chicago
Mountain Time   America/Denver
Mountain Time (no DST) America/Phoenix
Pacific Time    America/Los_Angeles
Alaska Time America/Anchorage
Hawaii-Aleutian America/Adak
Hawaii-Aleutian Time (no DST) Pacific/Honolulu
```

Comment: Where did you get this list from?

Comment: It is the list that is distilled from here: http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.america.php

Comment: The doc referenced by @CamdenS. does indeed contain a list of PHP time zones for "America". But I would still like to see official documentation that these few are all the time zones for the US. Also that doc does not say which time zone each correlates to as provided in this answer (Easter Time, Central, Etc). I suppose one could look up all the US time zones and make sure none are missing from this list (from the left). Then you could look up the places (on the right) and see if they match the time zone (on the left). Is this list really accurate?

Comment: This link shows all timezones: http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

Comment: This is the go-to list for the American developer, beyond this see here http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

Comment: Don't forget Puerto Rico: America/Puerto_Rico

Answer (score 57):

As deceze said, you can use the PER_COUNTRY flag.

```
$timezone_identifiers = DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers(DateTimeZone::PER_COUNTRY, 'US');
foreach($timezone_identifiers as $timezone_identifier) {
  echo "$timezone_identifier\n";
}
```

Output:

```
America/Adak
America/Anchorage
America/Boise
America/Chicago
America/Denver
America/Detroit
America/Indiana/Indianapolis
America/Indiana/Knox
America/Indiana/Marengo
America/Indiana/Petersburg
America/Indiana/Tell_City
America/Indiana/Vevay
America/Indiana/Vincennes
America/Indiana/Winamac
America/Juneau
America/Kentucky/Louisville
America/Kentucky/Monticello
America/Los_Angeles
America/Menominee
America/Metlakatla
America/New_York
America/Nome
America/North_Dakota/Beulah
America/North_Dakota/Center
America/North_Dakota/New_Salem
America/Phoenix
America/Shiprock
America/Sitka
America/Yakutat
Pacific/Honolulu
```

Comment: I believe this answer is the one that best answers the OP's request (in his comment) for something automated. It is a complete list and more future-proof.

Answer (score 7):

This will automatically get you a list of American timezones:

```
if (defined('DateTimeZone::AMERICA')) {
    // PHP 5.3+
    $timezoneIdentifiers = timezone_identifiers_list(DateTimeZone::AMERICA);
} else {
    // PHP 5.2
    $timezoneIdentifiers = timezone_identifiers_list();
    $timezoneIdentifiers = array_filter($timezoneIdentifiers, create_function('$tz', 'return preg_match("/^America\//", $tz);'));
}
```

Note that this will include South American, Canadian etc timezones as well though. You could play around with `DateTimeZone::PER_COUNTRY` as a filter to `timezone_identifiers_list` for PHP 5.3 and see if that gets you want you want, or filter the complete list for `US/`. The best choice is probably to handpick the timezones though.

Comment: Yeah I already got the list for America just wanted the United States only.

Answer (score 0):

Brute-force way to get ALL timezones per country using PHP's GEOIP. The code is not intended to look nice. You should call this only once and store the result somewhere.

```
$timezones = array();

foreach (range('A', 'Z') as $i) {
    foreach (range('A', 'Z') as $j) {
        $country = $i . $j;

        foreach (range('A', 'Z') as $k) {
            foreach (range('A', 'Z') as $l) {
                $region = $k . $l;

                if ($timezone = geoip_time_zone_by_country_and_region($country, $region)) {
                    $timezones[$country][$timezone] = true;
                }
            }
        }

        foreach (range(0, 99) as $m) {
            if ($timezone = geoip_time_zone_by_country_and_region($country, sprintf('%02d', $m))) {
                $timezones[$country][$timezone] = true;
            }
        }
    }
}

var_dump($timezones);
```