# PHP Time Zone Function

Tags: php, timezone, timestamp-with-timezone

I'm new to php. I'm building a web app for an online TV station and I'm working on a program schedule system. My problem is how to display the program time relative to the end user. So that a program that airs at 7am EST on the server would be displayed as 6am CST. Anybody know a simple solution? Thanks

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. You'll get a better answer if you include a code sample showing what you've tried already!

Comment: Documentation on PHP's date, time, and time zone support can be found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `DateTime` class, parse the program time in its local timezone then set the timezone to the end user's timezone and display it. Here's a somewhat simple example...

```
$dt = new DateTime('7am', new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));
echo $dt->format('r');
// Fri, 03 Oct 2014 07:00:00 -0400

$dt->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('America/Chicago'));
echo $dt->format('r');
// Fri, 03 Oct 2014 06:00:00 -0500
```

Comment: Please note that `CST` is not a valid PHP Timezone, but `US/Central` is.

Comment: @worldofjr weird, it works for me and as you can see from my example above, it is correct (-0600). In any case, this is just an example

Comment: Not valid though. I think it depends on your server sometimes. See [PHP: Other Timezones](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.others.php) and you'll notice it's not listed. In any case, those timezones are for backwards compatibility only. EST should use `America/New_York` for example.

Comment: Also see this SO question [List of US Time Zones for PHP to use?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4989209/list-of-us-time-zones-for-php-to-use).

Comment: @worldofjr apparently, you shouldn't use the `US/` prefixed zones either. I've updated my answer with *valid* timezones