# PHP Display Date Time with Offset

Tags: php, datetime

In php how can I display the current date and time with the timezone offset such as this:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Denver');
$now = new \DateTime('NOW');
echo $now->format("Y-m-d h:i:s"); 
//
```

This displays `2019-01-09 19:30:19`
 but I want it to display `2019-01-09 07:00:00` because I am in Mountain Time Zone

Answer (score 1):

Try to paste second parameter your timezone

```
$date = new DateTime('NOW', new DateTimeZone('America/Denver));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d h:i:s');
```

You could define wich timezone is fitting for you by this answer.

[List of US Time Zones for PHP to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4989209/list-of-us-time-zones-for-php-to-use#answer-12358976)

for getting all timezones names in you country. Then you pick your timezone and paste

```
$date = new DateTime('NOW', new DateTimeZone('Your Country/Your timezone'));
```

Answer (score 1):

When working with time zones and `DateTime()` objects you should be using `DateTimeZone()` instead of `date_default_timezone_set()`

```
$now = new \DateTime(null, new DateTimeZone('America/Denver'));
echo $now->format("Y-m-d h:i:s");
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/c1b1R)

Answer (score 1):

you have right code, but you have want to show time in 12 hours format. then you have use something like that.

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Denver');
$now = new \DateTime('NOW');
echo $now->format("Y-m-d h:i:s A");
```