# Why is PHP returning the wrong time in PDT?

Tags: php, datetime

My PHP Installation (7.4.22) returns the correct time for other timezones, but does not return the correct time for PDT. My Server (Ubuntu 18.04.2) Shows the correct time in UTC when logging in.

Example Script:-

```php
<?php
$date_str_8601 = '2021-10-03T12:30:00Z'; // Input 12:30 UTC
$dateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat(DateTime::ISO8601, $date_str_8601);
date_timezone_set($dateTime, timezone_open('PDT'));
echo 'PDT ' . date_format($dateTime, 'g:i A'); // Expected: PDT 5:30 AM
date_timezone_set($dateTime, timezone_open('Europe/London'));
echo ', London ' . date_format($dateTime, 'g:i A'); // Expected: London 1:30 PM
```

Expected Output:

`PDT 5:30 AM, London 1:30 PM`

Actual Output

`PDT 4:30 AM, London 1:30 PM`

Why is my code giving me the wrong time for PDT? Is there something about my configuration I can fix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`PDT` is not a supported time zone name. Use `America/Los_Angeles` instead.

See [DateTimeZone](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetimezone.construct.php), [Timezones America](https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.america.php) and [List of US Time Zones for PHP to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4989209/14853083)

[Update]
PHP supports a [list of time zone abbreviations](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetimezone.listabbreviations.php), which includes PDT. This list appears to map to all the supported time zones that use that abbreviation, thus `PDT` maps to time zone information for America/Los Angeles, America/Boise, and Asia/Manila, amongst others. These three places are in different time zones.

Further, the abbreviations list is compiled in for performance reasons, and won't reflect any updates to the system time zone database.

I haven't been able to ascertain exactly how PHP selects the timezone data from this abbreviation list. Suffice it to say that it's clear that it can't be relied on, and the full format name is the way to go.

Comment: Good advice and probably what @Thomas Harris should do, but it doesn't explain the behaviour demonstrated. If PDT is not supported, then surely the time should be returned in UTC? It looks like it is returning the winter time (PST?).

Comment: @thelem I did a bit more digging. See my updated answer.